# ErrorException controller@comment Not defined

Tags: laravel-5

My app in showing this error

> Action App\Http\Controllers\ComplainController@comment not defined.
>   (View:
>   /var/www/html/Chirag_Laravel/resources/views/backend/pages/ifa/complaint.blade.php)

But i have already entered the controller and the route funtions properly

`Controller` part:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Complaint;
use App\Status;
use common;
class ComplainController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index(Request $request)
    {   
    $user_data=$request->session()->get('user_name');
        $status=Status::SELECT('status')
                ->where('id','=',1)
                ->get();
        $reports=Complaint::Where('raised_by','=',"$user_data")->SELECT('*')->get();
        return view('backend.pages.ifa.complaint',compact('status','reports'));


    }







     public function store(Request $request)
     {

     // return  $data = $request->all();
     // echo carbon::now();
       $user=$request->session()->get('user_name');
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');;
     $date=date('Y:m:d');
     $month=date('m-y');
     $token= str_pad(mt_rand(1,99999999),8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

       $header=$request->input('issue_header');
       $description=$request->input('issue_description');
       $status=$request->input('status');
       $input=$request->all();

       $file= $request->file('document');

       $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($month.' '.'Report-docs',$name);
       $input['document']=$name;
         $doc = $input['document'];


                 Complaint::create(["ticket_no"=>"$token","issue_header"=>"$header","issue_description"=>"$description","document"=>"$doc","status"=>"$status","raised_on"=>"$date",'raised_by'=>"$user"]);
       //  //Complaint::create($input);
                 $message="Report Submitted Successfully";
                 $request->session()->put(['work_success'=>$message]);
                  return redirect('ifa-dashboard/report-problems');



     }
     public function common(Request $request)
     {
      //echo 1;
       $report_id=$request->get('report_id');
       $change_status=$request->get('clientStat');
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
         $date=date('Y:m:d H:i:s');
       for ($i=0; $i <1 ; $i++) { 
         # code...
        Complaint::Where('id','=',"$report_id")
              ->Update(['status'=>"$change_status"]);
            return redirect('ifa-dashboard/report-problems');
       }

     }

     public function comment($id,Request $request)
      {
        $user_name=$request->session()->get('user_name');
        $ticket=Complaint::Where('id','=',$id)
                ->SELECT('ticket_no')
                ->get();
        foreach($ticket as $tickets)
        {
         $tik=$tickets['ticket_no'];
          $comments=\DB::SELECT('SELECT comment,comment_by from comments where complaint_id=? AND comment_by=? or comment_by=? ORDER BY id DESC',[$tik,$user_name,'Admin']);
              return view('backend.pages.ifa.comment',compact('tik','id','comments','user_name'));
        }




      }
      public function getComment(Request $request)
      {
        $request->session()->put(['comment_success'=>'Comment Submitted Successfully']);
        $report_id=$request->session()->get('report_id');
        $complain=$request->get('tiko');
        $user_name=$request->get('user_name');
        $comment=$request->get('comment');
        //echo $complain_id."<br>".$comment;
        Comment::create(["complaint_id"=>"$complain","comment"=>"$comment","comment_by"=>"$user_name"]);
        return redirect()->back();

      }
}
```

Blade part:

```
<td><center><a href="{{action('ComplainController@comment', $report['id'])}}">Comment</a></center></td>
```

Cant find a way out

Comment: You need to define at your blade part if its a POST or GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ComplainController is available in controllers folder, if you have put this in a folder inside controller folder then change namespace in your ComplainController.
if ComplainController is available in App\Http\Controllers\Admin then namespace should be namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin; or you can simply use routes as

```
Route::get('ifa-dashboard/comment/{id}','ComplainController@comment');
```

Thanks

Comment: what changes you have made?

Comment: Route::get('ifa-dashboard/comment/{id}','ComplainController@comment');
Route::POST('ifa-dashboard/getComment','ComplainController@getComment');

Comment: share your complete controller file

Comment: i did check it please